# Is there a base R version of tidyr's unnest() function?

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

I've been using `tidyverse` quite a lot and now I'm interested in the possibilities of base R.

Let's take a look at this simple data.frame

```r
df <- data.frame(id = 1:4, nested = c("a, b, f", "c, d", "e", "e, f"))
```

Using `dplyr`, `stringr` and `tidyr` we could do

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(nested = str_split(nested, ", ")) %>% 
  unnest(nested)
```

to get (let's ignore the `tibble` part)

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 2
     id nested
  <int> <chr> 
1     1 a     
2     1 b     
3     1 f     
4     2 c     
5     2 d     
6     3 e     
7     4 e     
8     4 f
```

Now we want to rebuild this one using base R tools. So

```r
transform(df, nested = strsplit(nested, ", "))
```

gives use the `mutate`-part, but how can we `unnest()` this data.frame? I though of using `unlist()` but couldn't find a satisfying way.

Comment: Do you need something like `data.frame(id = rep(out$id, lengths(out$nested)), nested = unlist(out$nested))` where `out <- transform(df, nested = strsplit(nested, ", "))`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I thought about it for a while but wasn't able to find a fine solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `stack` on a `named` `list` in a single line

```
with(df, setNames(stack(setNames(strsplit(nested, ","), id))[2:1], names(df)))
```

-output

```
   id nested
1  1      a
2  1      b
3  1      f
4  2      c
5  2      d
6  3      e
7  4      e
8  4      f
```

---

If we use `transform`, then use `rep` to replicate based on the `lengths` of the `list` column

```
out <- transform(df, nested = strsplit(nested, ", "))
data.frame(id = rep(out$id, lengths(out$nested)), nested = unlist(out$nested))
```